# Java.lang.LinkageError RFT - Selenium - Appium

Tags: java, selenium, command-line, appium, rft

I am stuck in this situation, I have reviewed a lot of documentation but I cannot find the solution, I am working on a project that automates web and mobile apps, and sometimes both at the same time, because there is information that must be transferred between them.

**The automations work correctly when run from the IDE (RFT) itself**, but if I try to run it from the console it throws the following error.

```
exception_name = java.lang.LinkageError
exception_message = loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.findElement(Lorg/openqa/selenium/By;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebElement;" during creation of class "io/appium/java_client/DefaultGenericMobileElement": loader "com/rational/test/ft/util/FtClassLoader@c6ae7474" of class "io/appium/java_client/DefaultGenericMobileElement" and loader "com/rational/test/ft/util/FtClassLoader@a4fe6ba3" of class "org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement" have different types for the method signature
script_name = Platforms.Test.Test
script_id = Platforms.Test.Test.java
line_number = 40
exception_stack = at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at com.rational.test.ft.util.FtClassLoader.loadClass(FtClassLoader.java:159)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:854)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at com.rational.test.ft.util.FtClassLoader.loadClass(FtClassLoader.java:159)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:854)
at com.rational.test.ft.util.FtClassLoader.callRelatedClassLoaders(FtClassLoader.java:356)
at com.rational.test.ft.util.FtClassLoader.loadClass(FtClassLoader.java:163)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:854)
at Platforms.Test.Test.testMain(Test.java:40)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

This is how I run the automation from the command line, kernel.jar is a set of libraries packed with Ant that among others contains java-client-7.3.0 (io.appium.java_client), selenium.jar is selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59 (org.openqa. selenium):

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\bin\java" -classpath "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\FunctionalTester\bin\rational_ft.jar" com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft -datastore "C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project" -projectpath "C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project\libs\inuse\kernel.jar;C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project\libs\inuse\selenium.jar" -log "Project.Test.Test" -playback "Platforms.Test.Test" -args "Test"
```

The automation script is very simple, it imports a classes that contains the functionalities, which using selenium connects to a web portal, retrieves a security code and then using appium uses that code to authenticate in an app and do other operations, which I repeat everything works correctly if I run from the IDE itself.

```
public class Test extends TestHelper
{
    /**
     * 
     * @since  2020/08/21
     * @author jddeltoro
     */
    public void testMain(Object[] args) 
    {
        Framework fw =  Framework.getInstance();
        try {
            fw.initEnviromentTokens();
            
            WebAppAutomation waa= new WebAppAutomation(fw);
            waa.init();
            String code = wpa.reatriveSecurityCode();
            waa.quit();

            MobileAppAutomation maa= new MobileAppAutomation(fw);
            maa.init();
            maa.executeProcess(code);
            maa.quit();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Another important clue is that if I run a script from the command line that instantiates only Selenium or only Appium, the **java.lang.LinkageError** is not displayed, this indicates that the command is correct.
The reason for executing through the console is that I carry out the executions remotely, there are thousands of scripts and when one finishes I start the execution of another.

Note:
If i use installed java vm the exception is similar:

```
"java -classpath "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\FunctionalTester\bin\rational_ft.jar" com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft -datastore "C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project" -projectpath "C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project\libs\inuse\kernel.jar;C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project\libs\inuse\selenium.jar" -log "Project.Test.Test" -playback "Platforms.Test.Test" -args "Test"

exception_name = java.lang.LinkageError
exception_message = loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementById(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebElement;" the class loader (instance of com/rational/test/ft/util/FtClassLoader) of the current class, io/appium/java_client/DefaultGenericMobileDriver, and its superclass loader (instance of com/rational/test/ft/util/FtClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/openqa/selenium/WebElement used in the signature
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this using a different trigger command:

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\bin\javaw.exe" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project\libs\inuse\kernel.jar;C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project\libs\inuse\selenium.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\FunctionalTester\bin\rational_ft.jar" com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft -projectpath C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project -datastore C:\Workspaces\RFT\Project -idetype wswplugin -rt.interactive true -rt.log_format html -log Platforms.Test.Test -iterationcount ALL -rt.log_action false -rt.log_screen_snapshot false -playback Platforms.Test.Test
```